# Multiplication operator output variation on different values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

what is the difference between `*` and `**` in python? How the working of these two operators work according to PEMDAS and why there is variation in the output in the following scenario

- `16**(1/2)` yields 1
- `16**(0.5)` yields 4.0
- `16**0.5` also yields 4.0

but `1/2` = `0.5` then why there is difference in the output?

Answer (score 1):

- '*' means multiplication
- '**' means power

16 ** (0.5) means 16 to the power of 0.5, that is square root of 16 = 4

16 ** (1/2) seems to be the same. But 1/2 yields to integer calculation and answers 0. So, 16 to the power 0 = 1

The correct way would be

- 16 ** (1.0/2.0)
- 16 ** (float(1) / float(2))

Comment: `1./2` or `1/2.` is enough to make it floating point division, or `from __future__ import division` to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k, I learnt something from this. Forgot, its Python after all and not Java or C# :)

Answer (score 0):

- `16**(1/2)` is 16**0 in Python2 (it should work with Python3 however);
- `16**(0.5) is square root as expected
- `16**0.5` is the same as the previous one.

The issue comes here from the meaning of `/` in python2 (integer division).

Comment: No. `/` means division. The 'wrong' result is a result of the fact that two `int`s are being divided, **and therefore** integer division is carried out. As long as at least one of the values is a float, float division will be computed, as mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

in addtion to the answers so far, you can also do `1.0 / 2` to force float computation.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x version, any division converts to float :

```
>>>1.0/2.0
0.5

>>> 1/2
0.5
```

The same if you want to achieve in Python2.x, you have to convert interget into float manually.

```
>>> 1.0/2
0.5
```

or

```
>>> float(1)/float(2)
```

or
from future, import the division.

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/2
0.5
```